# как писать последовательные переменные через def на python

Tags: python

допустим, у меня есть 5 переменных.

```
a1 = 818181
a2 = 43834
a3 = 876272
a4 = 726187621
a5 = 854624
```

это просто абстрактные переменные
и надо через def, при этом не писать каждую переменную, вывести их в консоль последовательно.
я пробовал как-то так, не получилось

```
a1 = 546545
a2 = 18151188
a3 = 6378
a4 = 7872
a5 = 778378
i = 0
printing = 0
while i < 5:
    print(a(printing + 1))
```

помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Список используйте

Answer (score 2):

Условия выполнены:

1. через def
2. не писать каждую переменную
3. вывести их в консоль последовательно

Прошу учесть, что [`locals()`](https://pythonim.ru/osnovy/funktsiya-locals-v-python) используется преимущественно при отладке.

```
def print_a(l):
    for k, v in l.items():
        if k.startswith('a'):
            print(f'{k} = {v}')


a1 = 818181
a2 = 43834
a3 = 876272
a4 = 726187621
a5 = 854624

print_a(locals())
```

```
a1 = 818181
a2 = 43834
a3 = 876272
a4 = 726187621
a5 = 854624
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
a1 = 818181
a2 = 43834
a3 = 876272
a4 = 726187621
a5 = 854624

arr = [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5]
print(*arr, sep = "\n")
```

Результат

818181

43834

876272

726187621

854624

или так, если с def :) :

```
def printNumbers(*numbers):
    print(*numbers, sep = "\n")

printNumbers(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5)
```